# Binding NSOutlineView's selection index paths

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, cocoa-bindings, key-value-observing

I have a custom `<NSOutlineViewDataSource>`, for which I would its `NSOutlineView` to update a `selectionIndexPaths` property. I can't get `bind:toObject:withKeyPath:options:` to actually bind properly. Basically, I need my data source to know which item is selected.

When I bind to [`selectionIndexes`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/BindingsText/NSTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/NSTableView-DontLinkElementID_623) (declared by NSTableView) or [`selectionIndexPaths`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/BindingsText/NSOutlineView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/NSOutlineView-DontLinkElementID_328)  (declared by NSOutlineView), which the documentation indicates I should be able to (unless for some reason that's only available in IB), I get a runtime exception that the outline view isn't "key value coding-compliant" for either of those keys.

When I bind to [`selectedRowIndexes`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000118-SW79) (a fallback, since I would need to then take that information and reverse-engineer it to figure out which parent/child pair is selected), it updates the data source once, with the `NSIndexSet` in the data source frozen to its initial value. I don't set it manually, either. Further, I can't even bind `selectedRowIndexes` in the other direction, so the data source can update the outline view's selection. I get the same "key value coding-compliant" exception on the outline view.

I have an `@property` defined in my data source class, with a backing ivar, and I'm binding it from a controller class with references to the data source and the outline view, after data has been loaded, in `-awakeFromNib`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than binding `selectionIndexPaths`, which acted unreliably, I instead used my outline view's delegate to update the selection in the model on the `-outlineViewSelectionIsChanging:` and `-outlineViewSelectionDidChange:` notifications.

Answer (score 2):

Dov, have you considered using NSTreeController which is tailored to bindings? Alternatively, You can set your controller as the delegate of the outline view to receive notification of a selection with the method "-outlineViewSelectionDidChange"

[Source](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOutlineViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: I had been previously using NSTreeController, but I wanted more customized behavior. Also, `-outlineViewSelectionDidChange` only fires when the user clicks on a new row, not for keyboard navigation.

Comment: This is quite late, but here is a comment anyway. I'm putting together a custom view coordinated with an outline view. Arrow keys work fine for changing the selection (for me).  I can also find out what object is selected from the selectedIndex set.  Luckily, my objects know their parent as well as their children, so if I ever need the index set it's easy to compute.  I'm used to it, from NSTreeController, but I might not even need it.